# Old Style Grammar

Tags: grammar

> If a thing take place whereof the cause be not apparent, even though it be in accordance with nature, it appears wonderful. ...

Is it formal and valid English, or is it old style English, or is there a grammar or translation error? First, why not *takes* place instead of take place? Second, why not *is* not apparent instead of be not apparent?

(I am not sure if such questions are welcome in this platform. I am not a native English speaker. I am asking this question because I want to improve my English and because I encounter similar sentences occasionally. So I am not asking to translate it, but to explain the issue in general.)

The source of the above quotation is *The Science of Mechanics* by Ernst Mach (translated by T. J. McCormack, 6th ed. 1960, p. 13). The quotation is taken from Aristotle's *Mechanical Problems* (German trans. by Poselger, Hanover, 1881).

Comment: Don't you mean *olde* style grammar?

Comment: @Jake Regier - That's a good joke for native speakers but might be confusing for learners!  ('olde' is the old spelling for 'old')

Comment: The only thing that seems off to me is that "take" should have an s for subject-verb agreement... I mean, it's not "modern" English but it's understandable.

Comment: @Catija: You don't think *whereof the cause be not apparent* is hopelessly archaic phrasing?

Comment: The verbs are in the subjunctive mood, used for conditions contrary to fact, where the speaker is expressing doubt, and a few other places.  It appears today in a few frozen locutions ("Let it be.") or with the verb to be ("If I were a rich man, ...."), but rarely otherwise.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I said "it's not modern"...

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: I think you mean "*one* of the old spellings for 'old'."

Comment: Google-fu: https://books.google.com/books?id=GmH_CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA216&lpg=PA216&dq=%22whereof+the+cause+be+not+apparent%22&source=bl&ots=GESKpwsWT9&sig=g7L2hdXaUuYYFKWAfJNtge1P_L8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAmoVChMIh8m36bKDxwIVwzU-Ch2uQwry#v=onepage&q=%22whereof%20the%20cause%20be%20not%20apparent%22&f=false

Comment: @TimRomano So it's been transcribed slightly incorrectly... it seems that it should be "takes".

Comment: @Catija: "if a thing take place" would be consonant with "be not apparent". Perhaps the translator was trying to remain as close as possible to the grammar of the original 19th c. German.

Comment: Actually, the English translator added the subjunctive *be not apparent* which is not in the German (erscheint...offenbart). https://books.google.com/books?id=RZRTAAAAcAAJ&q=geschehe#v=snippet&q=wunderbar&f=false

Answer (score 4):

> If a thing take place whereof the cause be not apparent, even though
>   it be in accordance with nature, it appears wonderful. ...

1. The grammar is correct.
2. The language sounds as though it might have been written in the 17th century.
3. "whereof" is used nowadays only in legal documents.
4. 'If ... be'  is an example of English subjunctive. This would only be seen in the most formal of writing these days.

Have a look at this [Google ngram: whereof](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whereof&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhereof%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Solver - Did I say thereof? I can't spot it.  If you want to look up subjunctive, a useful place to start would be to Google  ***"if it be" subjunctive***. Also you can Google ***"English subjunctive"***

Comment: Because I'm actually curious, can you explain why "take" isn't "takes"? ... actually a comment on the question seems to show that the source material actually **is** "takes".

Comment: "If a thing take place ..." - again this is an old usage. Nowdays we would say, "If a thing should take place..."  You can call this subjunctive or irrealis.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a correct translation from old style English, it's hard to understand for native speakers too because it's not how we'd say things anymore.

A more modern way to say the same thing would be "If a thing takes place and the cause is not apparent, even though it's in accordance with nature, it appears to be wonderful".